# how to store and retrieve (_sh_SESSION) values in GAE

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

How I can store and easily query **session data** **(_sh_SESSION)** in google app engine datastore?
i am using **JPA.**

I am new to GAE, i read [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig).

Comment: Nothing to do with JPA; that is for persisting/retrieving data in a database and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Question : **i want to keep the user stay signed in into my app. How can i achieve this?**

You can use [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to Maintain session in android.

**Logic:**
When User enter his user credential for login. That time url is hits from your app at that time you start session in server side. However url is between the app and your Server.

Comment: Check my edited ans and why u want to mentain session on sever side if you use json

Comment: With the user credential like username and password

Comment: No not every time just once and maintain the session. with some user id or as your required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64984/discussion-between-w-i-z-a-r-d-and-user3756408).